# Can we update a sharepoint list page without sharepoint powershell snapin

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I got a requirement to automate, update of sharepoint list page on weekly basis. Can I update the sharepoint list page with powershell? I donot have access to sharepoint power shell snapins.

Comment: Please refer to : **[ask]**

Comment: Yes, you can. Question answered.

Comment: CSOM or SharePoint REST API are options that might work depending on what exactly you want to update.

Answer (score 0):

You can update sharepoint web parts on a sitepage with powershell, yes.  Not sure why you wouldnt have access to the snapins though?  Here is a script that would do the job for you:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -erroraction SilentlyContinue
Start-SPAssignment -Global
$Web = Get-SPWeb http://your/site/here
$Web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = $true

Try { 

    $CONTENT_TO_ADD_TO_PAGE = "New content"

    #Get the sitepage
    $file= $web.GetFile($web.Url +"/SitePages/YOURPAGE.aspx")
    if($file.Exists) {
        #Web Part Manager to get all web parts from the file
        $WebPartManager = $web.GetLimitedWebPartManager( $file,  [System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)

        #Iterate through each web part
        foreach($webPart in $WebPartManager.WebParts | Where {$_.title -eq "WEB PART NAME"}) {
                $XmlDoc = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
                $contentXml=$xmlDoc.CreateElement("content") 
                $contentXml.InnerText= $CONTENT_TO_ADD_TO_PAGE
                #Set content and Save
                $webpart.Content = $contentXml    
                $webPartManager.SaveChanges($webPart);
        }   
    }

} Finally {
    Remove-Variable file, $WebPartManager
    $Web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = $false
    $Web.Dispose()
    Stop-SPAssignment -Global
    [GC]::Collect()
}
```